# Is Littlewood's first principle worthwhile for the set of rationals in [0,1], or for the set of irrationals?

Tags: real-analysis

While Littlewood's first principle says any measurable set can be well approximated by a finite union of intervals, can a case be made that the approximation is "worthwhile" in some sense for the set of rationals in [0,1], or for the set of irrationals in [0,1]. For example, in the case of the set of rationals, a set consisting of just one rational is a closed subset whose difference with the rationals is a set of measure zero.  But it bears little resemblance to the full set of rationals.  In the case of the irrationals, (0,1) is an open set whose difference with set of irrationals has measure zero, which is, I admit, a reasonable outer approximation.  But I cannot conceive of a closed subset of the irrationals whose difference has small measure.  It would have to be a subset with measure close to one, with no rationals as limit points.

Comment: Are you familiar with fat Cantor sets?

Comment: I was not.  I'll look into them now.  Thanks.